# Use Age From Date And Create A Column Of Age Stages

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem of displaying Age Stage Using Only Date Of Birth , Here's My Query And Sample Image

```
SELECT 
res_fName,res_mName,
res_lName,rs.suffix,
rg.gender_Name,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,res_Bday,CURDATE()) AS age,
(SELECT IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,res_Bday,CURDATE()) <=1,'INFANT','')) Age_Stage 
FROM resident_detail rd 
LEFT JOIN ref_suffixname rs ON rd.suffix_ID = rs.suffix_ID 
LEFT JOIN ref_gender rg ON rd.gender_ID = rg.gender_ID
```

[SQL RESULT DISPLAY:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Wzp.png)
[image: SQL RESULT DISPLAY]

**Age Stages**

- Maternal and Newborn (*0 to 1 Month*)
- Babies (*1 to 12 Months*)
- Toddlers (*13 to 24 Months*)
- Preschoolers (*2 to 4 Years*)
- School Age Children (*5 to 8 Years*)
- Tweens (*9 to 12 Years*)
- Teenager (*13 to 19 Years*)
- Young Adult (*20 to 35 Years*)
- Middle-Aged Adults(*36 to 55 Years*)
- Senior (*56 to 100 Years*)

Comment: Do you want age stage for each age?

Comment: yeah, i already did getting the age from date using timestampdiff, then im having a problem displaying each stage of their age,

Comment: Do you know about Case statement?

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar i dont know case on sql ey, but i now case on PL, not on the sql

Comment: Try(answer posted) first for infant then further age stage cases will be applied.

Comment: are you there darren?

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar try to apply the age stages, thanks in advance, once you answered it and i will pick your answer

Comment: I have applied all the age stages. Kindly see the answer

Comment: are you there daren?

Comment: Up vote the answer

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar i click the upvote (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Case statement in order to determine Age Stage;

```
   SELECT res_fName,res_mName,res_lName,rs.suffix,rg.gender_Name,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,res_Bday,CURDATE()) AS age,
(case  
 when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Month,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=1) then 'Maternal and Newborn'
 when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Month,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Month,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=12) then 'Babies'
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Month,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=13 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Month,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=24) then 'Toddlers'
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=2 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=4) then 'Preschoolers'
 when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=5 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=8) then 'School Age Children'
 when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=9 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=12) then 'Tweens '
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=13 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=19) then 'Teenager'
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=20 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=35) then 'Young Adult'
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=36 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=55) then 'Middle-Aged Adults'
when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=56 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year,res_Bday,CURDATE())<=100) then 'Senior'
   end) Age_Stage 
FROM resident_detail rd LEFT JOIN ref_suffixname rs ON rd.suffix_ID = rs.suffix_ID LEFT JOIN ref_gender rg ON rd.gender_ID = rg.gender_ID
```